# in lightgbm regression, could we restrict the variance or abs(max-min) or something similar in a leaf

Tags: regression, lightgbm

IMO, the basic idea is that if variance is too large in the leaf (even if the mean is away a lot), the instances are possibly not well separated by the features yet. We might had better not consider such leaf.

Answer (score 0):

This might be it - `max_delta_step` -> [https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.2/Parameters.html#core-parameters:~:text=for%20early%20stopping-,max_delta_step,-%F0%9F%94%97%EF%B8%8E%2C%20default%20%3D](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.2/Parameters.html#core-parameters:%7E:text=for%20early%20stopping-,max_delta_step,-%F0%9F%94%97%EF%B8%8E%2C%20default%20%3D).

You also could consider setting a higher l1 and l2 regularization though.

Leaf_val = gamma = `-(grad_sum + l1_reg) / (hess_sum + l2_reg)`.

This might smooth out the leaf values a bit. Probably won't actually improve the model but might be worth playing around with.